# json: Cannot read property

Tags: json

I have this json object

```
const data=[{"meta":{"id":"feline","uuid":"e82c6957-4bbc-47c0-b2fa-156825a1700e","sort":"060757000","src":"collegiate","section":"alpha","stems":["feline","felinely","felines","felinities","felinity"],"offensive":false},"hwi":{"hw":"fe*line","prs":[{"mw":"\u02c8f\u0113-\u02ccl\u012bn","sound":{"audio":"feline01","ref":"c","stat":"1"}}]},"fl":"adjective","def":[{"sseq":[[["sense",{"sn":"1","dt":[["text","{bc}of, relating to, or affecting cats or the cat family"]]}]],[["bs",{"sense":{"sn":"2","dt":[["text","{bc}resembling a cat: such as"]]}}],["sense",{"sn":"a","dt":[["text","{bc}sleekly graceful"]]}],["sense",{"sn":"b","dt":[["text","{bc}{sx|sly||}, {sx|treacherous||}"]]}],["sense",{"sn":"c","dt":[["text","{bc}{sx|stealthy||}"]]}]]]}],"uros":[{"ure":"feline","fl":"noun"},{"ure":"fe*line*ly","fl":"adverb"},{"ure":"fe*lin*i*ty","prs":[{"mw":"f\u0113-\u02c8li-n\u0259-t\u0113","sound":{"audio":"feline02","ref":"c","stat":"1"}}],"fl":"noun"}],"et":[["text","Latin {it}felinus{\/it}, from {it}felis{\/it}"]],"date":"1681{ds||1||}","shortdef":["of, relating to, or affecting cats or the cat family","resembling a cat: such as","sleekly graceful"]},{"meta":{"id":"feline distemper","uuid":"5b9496ab-b949-4f7d-8f4e-c01ada9ea2f3","sort":"060758000","src":"collegiate","section":"alpha","stems":["feline distemper","feline distempers"],"offensive":false},"hwi":{"hw":"feline distemper"},"fl":"noun","def":[{"sseq":[[["sense",{"dt":[["text","{bc}{sx|panleukopenia||}"]]}]]]}],"date":"1942","shortdef":["panleukopenia"]},{"meta":{"id":"feline panleukopenia","uuid":"eb0a2e5b-94ab-465e-acef-6ec043016271","sort":"060759000","src":"collegiate","section":"alpha","stems":["feline panleukopenia"],"offensive":false},"hwi":{"hw":"feline panleukopenia"},"fl":"noun","def":[{"sseq":[[["sense",{"dt":[["text","{bc}{sx|panleukopenia||}"]]}]]]}],"date":"circa 1943","shortdef":["panleukopenia"]}]
```

Data consist of 3 arrays.  Only the 1st array has data.hwi.prs.  I want to capture the ***feline01*** from data.hwi.prs which is in audio tag.  The 2nd and 3rd array do not have data.hwi.prs tag.  It causes error when I try to extract audio name.

```
console.log(data.map((d) => d.hwi.prs.map((p) => p.sound.audio)));
```

It works when all 3 arrays contain data.hwi.prs element.
How can I get around this regardless if data.hwi.prs element present or not.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, what you have is an array of 3 objects.

If you are conditionally returning a value, then you wouldn't want to use map. Map is used when you want to manipulate and return a value for each item in an array. I would recommend using reduce instead, along with some nice optional chaining.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
This will return an array of all existing audio values.

```
const answer = data.reduce((acc, currentVal) => {
const audio = currentVal.hwi.prs?.[0].sound?.audio
return audio ? [...acc, audio] : acc
}, [])
```

Comment: I updated my question with real data I am working with.  Can you please help?

Comment: can you please elaborate on currentVal.hwi.prs?.[0].sound?.audio.  I can guess about '?.[0]' and 'sound?' (the way you used the question marks and dot), but what to get exact meaning.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It's called optional chaining. If you try to access a property of an object that doesn't exist, generally you would get a runtime error. With optional chaining, it just returns undefined https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 1):

This is a JS object contained in an array, referencing the Array[0] will target the JS object. For example,

```
let theArray = [{1, 2, 3}]
let theObject = theArray[0]
```

A `try...catch` statement would help you to handle the errors if it works well when the value exists. The following would only get the value if no error exceptions are thrown.

```
tags = []
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  try { 
    let captured = data[i].hwi.prs.sound.audio
    tags.append(captured)
  } catch {
    console.log('No values found')
  }
}
```